# Change the color in the Swagger API explorer documentation

Tags: restler

I am implementing API calls that are used to delete data in 2 ways via DELETE and GET requests:

```
@url DELETE /{id}
@url GET /delete/{id}
```

Is there a way to make the Swagger to color in red the GET request too?
They are used for same purpose - to delete data so it is natural.
This way it will be very intuitive for the API user!
Currently only DELETE requests are in red.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colours are for the request methods so it should be left as it is. Your description should do the explaining

```
GET /deltete/{id}
```

is **not** the RESTful way

Comment: Yes, for sure using `GET` request for delete operations is not by specification, but actually this is what my client expect, so I don't have much choice here ...

If I develop it, will you consider to incorporate a patch to the @url annotation that specifies the color for the Swagger?

Comment: If you surely want to do this, do it at the explorer's javascript level by looking if the url contains the word delete

Comment: Here is how it looks like with only the <h3> tag changed to red color, when delete word is present in the URL:
[picture](https://s3.amazonaws.com/AMilkov/Restler_Swagger_delete_red_color.jpg)

Also made a pull request if you like the change:
https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-API-Explorer/pull/3

Comment: I will manually merge it into hacks branch so anyone who needs it can make use of it